# FFmpeg capture RTSP stream only audio, black screen

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ip-camera, rtsp

I have a Foscam IP camera for which i have access to the RTSP address.
If i use VLC, the stream is working fine.
I wanted to capture it using FFmpeg, using the command `ffmpeg -i <address> -codec copy -t 10 out.mov`. All i get though is audio with a black screen.
From the logs i get

```
Input file #0 (rtsp://*:554/videoMain):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 226 packets read (2300933 bytes);
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 169 packets read (81120 bytes);
  Total: 395 packets (2382053 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (camera.mov):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 1 packets muxed (81865 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 168 packets muxed (80640 bytes);
  Total: 169 packets (162505 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
```

So, i don't know why only 1 packet gets muxed from the video stream.
Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Which codec does the camera use? Quicktime  (.mov) does not support all codecs.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @EugenRieck i forgot to mention that i actually had it going once, and .mov worked just fine. Recently i discovered that ommiting the -t  option will make it work but i need to stop it manually.

Comment: @Gyan https://pastebin.com/ybPUb5Md

Comment: Looks like a very large GOP ... try `-t 60` and report back